# How to detect which view is touched?

Tags: cocoa-touch, touch, layoutsubviews

Suppose I have a button that everytime I clicked it will generate a random number of subviews. Is there anyway to detect the subview touched?

Comment: I already know there's a way that I add all the generated view to an array and do traversing through the array to get the touched view. But, I don't know if there is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of touchesBegan method and use the view property of the UITouch instance passed:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //use touch.view property to get the subview touched
}
```

Remember to set the property *userInteractionEnabled* to YES in each of your subviews.